# Is this a time loop?

Tags: plot-explanation, lucifer

In *Lucifer* S06 we meet Rory who is Lucifer's daughter that travels from ~50 years in the future (estimated based on Chole's age at the end because Rory seems to have grown up in a weird way).

She is then pulled back into her timeline after having made peace with Lucifer.

When (and "where") does she come back? The scene with old Chloe does not show her angry (which is the trigger for her to time travel), was that a one-time time loop where she comes back before Chloe dies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a loop, more of a "time out elsewhen".

> When (and "where") does she come back?

Rory comes back at exactly the time she left, at Chloe's bedside as she is dying.

Essentially, she returns to her "present" immediately after she leaves (as you would expect) having made peace with Lucifer.

For her, she grew up exactly the same way, with Lucifer absent. Her anger is so intense as Chloe's life ends that she self-actualizes back to Lucifer's time.

As soon her time with Lucifer is over, she returns to exactly the same time she left but with all her anger issues resolved.

So no "loop" as such, just a period spent in an earlier time period.